# Get data from previous years dynamically

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with columns `id, fname, date_field`. `date_field`'s records are:

```
2011-03-01
2012-03-01
2013-03-01
2014-03-01
2015-03-01
2016-03-01
```

I want the data for the past 2 years for each record from that date which the table has.

For example:

- 2012 year having only one data before that is 2011
- 2013 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2012 and 2011
- 2014 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2013 and 2012
- 2015 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2014 and 2013
- 2016 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2015 and 2014

Note: Need to work dynamically for whatever data is in table, not by entering the date manually.

I want the query for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a simple join and intervals. Assuming the table with your data is named `mydata` and the table you mention in your question with a list of dates named `mydates`, you could issue the following query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.fname, d.date_field, dat.*
FROM mydates d
JOIN mydata dat
    ON (dat.date_field >= (d.date_field - interval 2 years) 
    AND dat.date_field < d.date_field)
ORDER BY 3, 1;
```